# Conditional probability question, joint probability for discrete random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have a homework question that I want to make sure I'm getting it right.

This is a joint probability table for the proportions of survey respondents who smoke and who have had heart attacks.

<kbd>Smoker</kbd> <kbd>Non-Smoker</kbd>
<kbd>Heart Attack</kbd>      <kbd>0.03</kbd>      <kbd>0.03</kbd>              
<kbd>No Heart Attack</kbd><kbd>0.44</kbd>      <kbd>0.50</kbd>

If a person is a smoker, are they more likely to have had a heart attack than someone who is not a smoker?

So I know that $P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

So I could think of the question like: *Find the conditional probability that a randomly selected person is a victim of a heart-attack, given that they’re a smoker/ non-smoker.*

$ P(X = Smoker \cap Y = Heart Attack) = 0.03  $
    $     P(X = NonSmoker \cap Y = Heart Attack) = 0.03  $
$P(Y) = 0.06$

That would mean that a smoker and a non-smoker would both have a $\dfrac{0.03}{0.06}$ chance of having a heart attack?

This defies my intuition because $\dfrac{3}{47}$ smokers get heart attacks, while only $\dfrac{3}{53}$ non-smokers get heart attacks.

Comment: $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$, intersection not union.

Comment: Thanks @DonkeyKong, I fixed it, just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *given* that they are a smoker/non-smoker. So your math is correct for what you have expressed, however you've done the conditional probabilities backwards. You are interested in $P(\text{ heart attack }| \text{ smoker })$ and $P(\text{ heart attack }| \text{ non-smoker })$. Calculating these will give you a more intuitive result for your question.

In the general case, consider $P(A|B)$ reading as "*the probability of $A$ given $B$*". Then your formula $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ should hopefully make some intuitive sense looking at your denominator.

Answer (score 1):

> $ P(X = Smoker$ | $Y = Heart Attack) = 0.03  $
>     $     P(X = NonSmoker$ | $Y = Heart Attack) = 0.03  $
>     $P(Y) = 0.06$

No, from the table you have *joint* probabilities:

$ P(X = \textsf{Smoker} \cap Y = \textsf{Heart Attack}) = 0.03  $
$ P(X = \textsf{Non-Smoker}\cap Y = \textsf{Heart Attack}) = 0.03 $
$ \therefore P(Y=\textsf{Heart Attack}) = 0.06$

Then you calculate ${\large P}\big(X=\textsf{Smoker}\mid Y=\textsf{Heart Attack}\big) = 0.50$

This is the probability that someone is a smoker *given* that they have had a heart attack.

Now, according to the table it *is* slightly more likely for a smoker to have a heart attack than for a non-smoker. 
$$P(Y=\textsf{Heart Attack}\mid X=\textsf{Smoker}) = \frac{0.03}{0.03+0.44} = \frac 3{47} \\ P(Y=\textsf{Heart Attack}\mid X=\textsf{Non-Smoker}) = \frac{0.03}{0.03+0.50} = \frac 3{53}$$
However there are only slightly more non-smokers than smokers over all.   This happens to balance out so that there are an equal number of smokers and non-smokers who have had heart-attacks.

Comment: You were right, I wrote my joint probabilities wrong. I correct it. Thank you for your answer!